# How do I fix npm vulnerabilities that require semver-major dependency updates?

Tags: npm, dependency-management, npm-audit

I cloned ParaViewWeb from https://github.com/kitware/paraviewweb then did the following;-

```
$ npm install
$ npm audit fix
```

Leaving me with this:

```
found 42 vulnerabilities (9 low, 23 moderate, 10  high) in 41716 scanned packages
14 vulnerabilities require semver-major dependency updates.
28 vulnerabilities require manual review.
```

How do I fix the 14 vulnerabilities that require semver-major dependency updates?

Answer (score 6):

When you run `npm audit`, there should be a line telling you how to update it, e.g.:

```sh
# Run  npm install --save-dev example@5.0.2  to resolve 1 vulnerability
# SEMVER WARNING: Recommended action is a potentially breaking change
```

Just execute that to fix it.

Comment: Only works if there is a current fix though.

Comment: "Just execute that" is correct, but not right -> one should test whether the changes are actually breaking anything.

Comment: Of course, but you can add that advice to most answers on StackOverflow... e.g. the other ones here. Should be obvious in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

If you are already sure that you need to run all that updates then use:

```
npm audit fix --force
```

From [npm Docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-audit)

> If the chain of metavulnerabilities extends all the way to the root project, and it cannot be updated without changing its dependency ranges, then npm audit fix will require the --force option to apply the remediation. If remediations do not require changes to the dependency ranges, then all vulnerable packages will be updated to a version that does not have an advisory or metavulnerability posted against it.

Comment: should we run it with `sudo`

Comment: if you can use other npm command without sudo then no.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in my situation, there currently is no fix.

You may have to complete the fix yourself:
Go into the package and change it's package.json version manually.

OR

Open an issue on the package and hope its still being maintained by the creator.

https://docs.npmjs.com/auditing-package-dependencies-for-security-vulnerabilities

has a list of suggested fixes.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade npm through this command

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

Comment: This question is not about updating npm itself.

Comment: Thank  you for the correction.